# Adding strings returns empty string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, loops, parsing

My goal is for this function to return only "03.12.21, 16:12:52". Currently only "]" is returned.

```js
let txt = `[03.12.21, 16:12:52] Firstname Lastname: Some text [03.12.21, 16:14:30] Firstname Lastname: Some text`;

console.log(parseDate()); // "]"

function parseDate() {
  for (let i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    let char = txt[i];
    let date = "";
    date += char;
    if (char === "]") {
      return date;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Declare `date` outside of the loop

Comment: kingkupps was right, you should declare the date outside, but you still need to remove the square brackets again to get the final result. You can use Regex and get the desired result
text.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `let date = "";` outside of the loop (you are resetting it each iteration)

```js
let txt = `[03.12.21, 16:12:52] First Name: Some text [03.12.21, 16:14:30] Felix Krückel: Some text`;

console.log(parseDate()); // "]"

function parseDate() {
  let date = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    let char = txt[i];
    date += char;
    if (char === "]") {
      return date;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I completely overlooked that. Should I delete my question, because I don't think this is any helpful to others.

Comment: There are no silly questions when you are learning. But yep, this place is kinda... strict about this, so it's up to you